# Tor Browser Bundle Firefox error

Tags: macos, firefox

I just installed the Tor Browser Bundle (1.0.24).  Vidalia launches with no problems.  Tor connections are created.  However, Firefox doesn't start.  When I manually click on the Firefox app in the Vidalia bundle, I get the following error:

```
You can't open the application Firefox.app because it may be damaged or incomplete.
```

Is this a Lion-specific error, or is it something I'm overlooking.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Snow Leopard, if I just close it all and start it again it works fine the second time.  Alway fails on the first invocation.  I haven't debugged it further.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, the second time it works fine on Lion.  Go figure... Many thanks!

Comment: @newmacfan Welcome, please give a correct answer an up vote and mark it as accepted if it solved your problem :)